# start php web server from any folder

Tags: php

I want to start a php server from a folder in my ubuntu system I tried the following command.

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

But it is not starting the server. I am getting the following output

```
Usage: php [options] [-f] <file> [--] [args...]
       php [options] -r <code> [--] [args...]
       php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -R <code> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...]
       php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -F <file> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...]
       php [options] -- [args...]
       php [options] -a

  -a               Run as interactive shell
  -c <path>|<file> Look for php.ini file in this directory
  -n               No php.ini file will be used
  -d foo[=bar]     Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'
  -e               Generate extended information for debugger/profiler
  -f <file>        Parse and execute <file>.
  -h               This help
  -i               PHP information
  -l               Syntax check only (lint)
  -m               Show compiled in modules
  -r <code>        Run PHP <code> without using script tags <?..?>
  -B <begin_code>  Run PHP <begin_code> before processing input lines
  -R <code>        Run PHP <code> for every input line
  -F <file>        Parse and execute <file> for every input line
  -E <end_code>    Run PHP <end_code> after processing all input lines
  -H               Hide any passed arguments from external tools.
  -s               Output HTML syntax highlighted source.
  -v               Version number
  -w               Output source with stripped comments and whitespace.
  -z <file>        Load Zend extension <file>.

  args...          Arguments passed to script. Use -- args when first argument
                   starts with - or script is read from stdin

  --ini            Show configuration file names

  --rf <name>      Show information about function <name>.
  --rc <name>      Show information about class <name>.
  --re <name>      Show information about extension <name>.
  --ri <name>      Show configuration for extension <name>.
```

but i googled this many times and I did not find any solution.How should I proceed?Please help

Comment: I can't see the option "-S" in the list of available arguments. What server are you using?

Comment: What does `php -v` show? Built-in server is only available on 5.4+

Answer (score 16):

If you using apache then open terminal and type
cd your/project/directory

To switch project directory
Then type 
php -S localhost:8000

Answer (score 5):

Go CMD in Windows

C:\PHP\php.exe -S localhost:8000 -t "C:\PHP\www\root"

C:\PHP\php.exe -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t "C:\PHP\www\root"

for ethernet(Share to World If port on in your modem)

C:\PHP\php.exe -S 192.168.1.240:8000 -t "C:\PHP\www\root"

Answer (score 1):

I understood I had to install php5-cli and I had to update to php 5.4 .Now It is working